# Track unique visits on a facebook tab application?

Tags: php, facebook, fbml

I was wondering if i can track the unique visitors on my facebook app (inside a fanpage tab).

FB doens't allow any kind of cookies do they? Are there any other workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you could put google analytics into a fan page.
[I found this link.](http://socialmediaseo.net/2010/03/11/google-analytics-facebook-fan-page/)

Comment: I know this link. I already build a (maybe better) solution based on another lib. But still the same question: How to track unique visiorts. Even your link has no solution?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this page [facebookapplication](http://www.facebookapplicationdevelopment.org/category/analytics/) has many different ways.